# Why does VS2010 remove my references?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reference

In a small console application I'm writing to test something I need to add a reference to one of the DLLs built from a build of another solution. The Add References dialog works perfectly; after I browse to the DLL on disk and add it I see it with a green tick and it appears in the list of references in Solution Explorer. All fine so far, but when I close the Add References dialog, the reference just added simply disappears from the list of references in Solution Explorer.

What on earth is going on? Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: OK, I'm an idiot. I was trying to reference a non-Silverlight DLL in a Silverlight project. Now I worked that out and referenced the Silverlight version, I have no problem. In my defence, it is Friday afternoon. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referencing a non-Silverlight DLL in a Silverlight will appear to work until the Add References dialog is closed, when the references simply disappears from the project's list of references. No warning or error message is displayed.